# How can I send smtp message to a partiicular IP and port?

Tags: .net, smtp

i want to test a home grown service that listens to a specific port like 12345 and parses out smtp message parts like from, to, body...

I want to make a test harness for my listener and am having trouble creating somethign that will generate smtp messages over a specific port number to a specific ip ( the ip/port where my listener is running)

i tried to send via a .net console app and it fails because i am forced to specify an smtp server to send my messages through and the one i have wont work for this because of security.

if i remember correct i should be able to telnet or one way or another use the command line to send emails to an ip and port. Basically i dont care how this gets done as long as im able to somehow send mail messages to my listener.

my sending app:

```
int count = 3;
for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{

    MailMessage message = new MailMessage("sender@ml.com", "recep@ml.com");
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(IPAddress.Loopback.ToString(), 8000);
    message.Body = "test mail #" + i.ToString();
    client.Send(message);

    Console.WriteLine("mail " + i.ToString() + " Sent");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
Console.WriteLine("DONE!");
```

my listener app:

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 8000);
TcpClient client;
NetworkStream ns;

listener.Start();

Console.WriteLine("Awaiting connection...");
client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted!");

ns = client.GetStream();

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ns))
{
writer.WriteLine("220 localhost SMTP server ready.");
writer.Flush();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ns))
{
    string response = reader.ReadLine();

    if (!response.StartsWith("HELO") && !response.StartsWith("EHLO"))
    {
    writer.WriteLine("500 UNKNOWN COMMAND");
    writer.Flush();
    ns.Close();
    return;
    }

    string remote = response.Replace("HELO", string.Empty).Replace("EHLO", string.Empty).Trim();

    writer.WriteLine("250 localhost Hello " + remote);
    writer.Flush();

    response = reader.ReadLine();

    if (!response.StartsWith("MAIL FROM:"))
    {
    writer.WriteLine("500 UNKNOWN COMMAND");
    writer.Flush();
    ns.Close();
    return;
    }

    remote = response.Replace("RCPT TO:", string.Empty).Trim();
    writer.WriteLine("250 " + remote + " I like that guy too!");
    writer.Flush();

    response = reader.ReadLine();

    if (!response.StartsWith("RCPT TO:"))
    {
    writer.WriteLine("500 UNKNOWN COMMAND");
    writer.Flush();
    ns.Close();
    return;
    }

    remote = response.Replace("MAIL FROM:", string.Empty).Trim();
    writer.WriteLine("250 " + remote + " I like that guy!");
    writer.Flush();

    response = reader.ReadLine();

    if (response.Trim() != "DATA")
    {
    writer.WriteLine("500 UNKNOWN COMMAND");
    writer.Flush();
    ns.Close();
    return;
    }

    writer.WriteLine("354 Enter message. When finished, enter \".\" on a line by itself");
    writer.Flush();

    int counter = 0;
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();

    while ((response = reader.ReadLine().Trim()) != ".")
    {
    message.AppendLine(response);
    counter++;

    if (counter == 1000000)
    {
        ns.Close();
        return;  // Seriously? 1 million lines in a message?
    }
    }

    writer.WriteLine("250 OK");
    writer.Flush();
    ns.Close();
    // Insert "message" into DB
    Console.WriteLine("Received message:");
    Console.WriteLine(message.ToString());
}
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: A nice open source program for making TCP connections from the command line is called "Netcat"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SMTP address and port you are forced to specify is the address and port of the application you want to test.

Emails over SMTP are in most cases relayed from server to server without any modification and using the same transport protocol. So wether you deliver directly to your application or to a relay server (like ISP's email server) doesn't really matter for the sender. It sees no difference.

The difference is that your ISP's server probably isn't able to relay the email to your application as it requires MX-record in DNS and correct firewalling/portforwarding to your app.

You can even configure a SMTP profile in Outlook to deliver to your application directly. Just specify app ip and port as SMTP server.

To use telnet:

```
telnet ip port
helo me
mail from: <some@domain.com>
rcpt to: <some@domain.com>
data
Subject: Ho Ho Ho
From: Santa 

Hello!
.
```

The server will acknowledge each line you type in, usually with english text.

Note the empty line between header and body, and the single dot on the last line to end message.

Comment: this doesn't work. I get a "could not open connection to host..." error

Comment: Then you are not listening on the port. Try `netstat -anb` and see if the program is actually listening on the port. Check firewall settings. Telnet works for sure. Syntax: `telnet mail.messaging.microsoft.com 25`. Hope this helps. :)